# Parallelizing/Speeding up Unique Substring Generation Technique

Tags: python, string, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to generate unique combinations with repetitions of 4 characters (say a, b, c & d for a python script that I am coding.

```
{Depth_value --> Output To Be Generated}

 - 1 --> [a, b, c, d]
 - 2 --> [a, b, c, d, aa, ab, ac, ad, ba, bb, bc, bd, ca, cb, cc, cd, da, db, dc, dd]
 - 3 --> [a, b, c, d, aa, ab, ac, ad, ba, bb, bc, bd, ca, cb, cc, cd, da, db, dc, dd, aaa, aab, aac, aad, ..., ddd]
 - .
 - .
 - .
 - N --> [a, b, c, d, aa, ab, ac, ad, ba, bb, bc, bd, ca, cb, cc, cd, da, db, dc, dd, aaa, aab, aac, aad, ..., (ddd...d)]
```

---

## EDIT1

```
UniquePatterns = ["".join(x) for i in range(1, depth + 1) for x in product(*['abcd'] * i)]
```

Executing ^ code takes less than a second. I think its what I am doing with the result of this statement that is causing the bottleneck.

```
depth = int(sys.argv[1])
    UniquePatterns = ["".join(x) for i in range(1, depth + 1) for x in product(*['ATCG'] * i)]
    print("Scanning dataset for" + str(len(UniquePatterns)) + " unique patterns!")

    UniqueCountPatterns = UniquePatterns
    GDS = {}
    GDS_UniqueCount = dict(zip(UniqueCountPatterns, [0 for i in range(1, NumberOf(UniqueCountPatterns)+1)]))
    GDS['UniqueCount'] = GDS_UniqueCount

    mngr = Manager()
    GDS_Links = mngr.dict()
    GDS_Links = dict(zip(UniquePatterns, [0 for i in range(1, NumberOf(UniquePatterns)+1)]))
    for l in dict(zip(UniquePatterns, [0 for i in range(1, NumberOf(UniquePatterns)+1)])):
        GDS_Links[l] = dict(zip(UniquePatterns, [0 for i in range(1, NumberOf(UniquePatterns)+1)]))
```

Any suggestions for efficiently populating dictionaries?

---

Thats how I am generating my list of unique patterns. While, that works pretty efficiently up till a depth value of 6, it starts taking a lot of time to generate patterns beyond that value.

My overall python script is a heavily parallelized script and the large duration of time taken to calculate the unique combinations beyond a 'depth' variable value beyond 6, it is turning out to be a bottleneck in my overall process.

Is there a possibility of parallelizing that code to efficiently and effectively generate unique combinations is 'acceptable' time. (Definition of 'acceptable' in the context of my application can range from a few seconds to the order of ~1minute).

I tried to parallelize some aspect of this computation by using a core process to calculate unique combinations with repetitions of some length in one process using multiprocessing in the following manner.

```
from itertools import product, chain
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process, Manager


def logic_patterncounting(inp1):
    return ["".join(x) for x in product(*['abcd'] * inp1)]


# UniquePatterns = ["".join(x) for i in range(1, 7 + 1) for x in product(*['ATCG'] * i)]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    depth = 2
    UniquePatterns = []
    pool = Pool()
    UniquePatterns = chain(*pool.map(logic_patterncounting, range(1, depth + 1)))
    print(list(UniquePatterns))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

This is not the best way to achieve what I want. How can I increase computation of the same for larger values of depth?

---

## Workaround Solution

Run a separate process that keeps generating unique patterns and stores them in a separate file. The time taken to generate unique patterns is still large for larger depth values, however availability of these patterns at time 0 of execution of main application fixes the bottleneck. Code the main application to make use of readily available list of patterns by reading contents of the file into either a dictionary or list structure (depending on usage).

P.S. I DO NOT WANT TO RESORT TO THE WORKAROUND unless NO solution is possible otherwise.

Comment: Since you're building up values by length, maybe you could (not using multiprocessing) optimize it by reusing previous lists.  You would only ever need to call product() with two sequences then.  E.g. 2 at a time would be one at a time times itself, 3 at a time would be one at a time times 2 at a time, 4 at a time would be 2 at a time * 2 at a time, etc.

Comment: When I run your line of code generating the permutations, it hardly takes any time at all -- less that 1 second for `depth = 10`, generating `1398100` permutations. (a) Are you sure that you understand what is causing your larger program to be slow. And (b) how large of a `depth` do you need to support? For `depth = 13`, it takes about 9 seconds, producing `89478484` permutations. In the latter case, I don't build a just -- just iterate over the results.

Comment: @FMc o.0 if i start the python3.4 shell and try the code it takes forever to process. Although if I run the script containing just the one line of code and import statement independently using the command line, it processes in less than a second like you suggested. It is highly possible that the bottleneck might exist somewhere else in the larger program.

Comment: @FMc  It is highly possible that the bottleneck might exist somewhere else in the larger program. (a) The reason I identified this as the bottleneck is because in my execution of the larger program, if I reduce the depth size from 6 to 3 or 4, I can complete my larger program execution (which is computationally intensive) in about 5 minutes or so. (b) I need to support a depth value of up to 12.

Comment: The line ``UniquePatterns = [...]`` runs in less than one second for ``depth = 10``.  Maybe you're trying to run instead only the part ``[...]``, which does take forever trying to print the whole resulting list.

Comment: @PatrickMaupin I will try building a method around those lines, however doesn't the product function also use that idea to generate the permutations?

Comment: @user2809541 If you run code like this in the Python shell (aka the REPL), you have to be careful to assign return values to variables. Otherwise, Python tries to print the list ... which will indeed take forever. And no, the `product()` function yields values in a lazy fashion (as they are consumed). It does not build a giant list in advance, and it certainly doesn't try to print giant lists.

Comment: You're aware that every additional ``depth`` takes 5 times longer to process, right?  If it takes 5 minutes for a depth of 4, it will take 1953125 minutes for a depth of 12.  To run that in 24 hours you'd need a machine with 1357 cores.

Comment: @FMc Understood. I overlooked the fact that the python shell is trying to print the list also. I edited the question a bit. Any recommendations after the edit?

Comment: @ArminRigo For now, I need to setup the application to reach a depth of 6. Post that I will scale the application to make use of a distributed computing framework

Comment: @user2809541 It looks like you are generating the same huge list several times: `[0 for i in range(1, NumberOf(UniqueCountPatterns)+1)]`. That seems unnecessary. Even worse (maybe I'm reading this wrong), you seem to be generating that list inside of a big `for` loop.

Comment: @ user2809541 Regarding your question, "Any suggestions for efficiently populating dictionaries?" My suggestion is don't do it. A million dicts with a million entries each won't work. You need a different approach. Do you really need a million copies of the same data?

Comment: @FMc Smart observation! I need to run [0 for i in range(1, NumberOf(UniqueCountPatterns)+1)] to initialize all dictionary keys to 0. If I don't initialize the dictionary key values to 0 then updating them later on in my program does not work.

Comment: @FMc To be honest I am not that inclined to do it either, however the output of my program needs to be a json file which contains that structure. Alternatively I can use a numpy array during computation and then extract a dictionary out of it and then dump it into a json file, but I have not explored that option yet. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: @user2809541 I don't have enough context to give good advice, but just one of these dictionaries will be massive. You can't create a large number of such dictionaries. It will be too slow and eventually you'll just run out of memory.